# How to handle "reference data" (static data) in the Google App Engine datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling

I have an application I am working on where I have a set of data that, while not technically static, will not change very often (say, 3 or 4 times a year on average).  However, some of this data is interrelated.

An example of this type of data would be states and counties - ideally, we would like to know all of the states available when putting in an address or location, but we would also like to know the counties available for each state, so we can display that information appropriately to the user (i.e. filtering out the inappropriate counties when a user has a state selected).

In the past, I have done this in a relational database by having a state and county table, where the county is linked back to the state it belongs in, and the state and counties are linked to any tables that need their information.

This data is not owned however, and in the Google datastore it seems like the locking transaction mechanism will cause locks to occur even though we are not actively modifying this data.  What is the best way to handle this type of data?  Is it to have an entity for the pieces that does not have a parent (parent of None/null)?  Will this cause locking problems in the future?

Comment: Why do you think that the transaction mechanism will cause locks? Transactions only apply to entity groups. What entity do you expect to be making transacted writes against?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I am talking about the entities I am loading up - in this example, the States and Counties specifically.  I am not planning on doing writes to them, but I thought I read that reading during a transaction would cause a lock on multiple entity groups if multiples were read - I could very much be mistaken on this though.

Comment: I think you're mistaken on that.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith Ahh, OK then, that makes more sense.  Thanks!

Comment: App Engine's datastore layer is lock-free - it uses optimistic concurrency, not locking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd consider storing this in an optimized data structure inside your code and updating it manually. The performance gain will be huge, and since google charges you for that, you will end up thanking for it.

The idea is to mix this fixed data structures with your database, so you give each country (or whatever) an id, and you reference it in your models.

A simple approach is making a list of countries and each have a list of states in them. You can load them in **def main():**, before you run the app. Of course this will bring all sorts of problems if you are not careful, but if you are, you should be fine.

A more advanced one would be to keep in memory only the most used, and lazy load and dump countries on the fly.

Comment: "Of course this will bring all sorts of problems if you are not careful" - what problems?  I am really new to Python AND GAE, so I am not seeing the exact problem there.  Thanks for the answer too - really helpful.  :)  What about having the data structures defined in a constants-like .py script?  Would that work similar to the main method you mention above?

Comment: sure, just run in before you run the app, and def main(): is a great place.

Comment: One problem I see could possibly happening is assigning and id to a country, then comes a new developer, changes it, and your hole database doesn't make sense anymore. Thas why I say you should be careful, as If you were a MySql engine!

Comment: Thanks for the responses - not having it in the database does make the ID portion important to sort out.  Thank you again.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest adding stuff to main. This runs on every invocation, not just at import time. Do it at module-level, or the first time you need it in code.